# Dynamically created image file cannot be found in Gallery or image picker in Android

Tags: android, image, android-gallery, android-file

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am creating image file from bitmap then save it to device. The process of creating image file from bitmap and save image to device is okay. The problem is I cannot find that created image in gallery. But the file really exist when I search it from file manager.

Here is my code:

```
File file = null;
try{
    String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpeg";
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileName);

    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }

    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    template.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    os.close();
    Toast.makeText(context,"Templated saved to your device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (Exception e)  {
    Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

As you can see, I save it in the picture folder. I tried save it in download folder as well. File saved to device successfully but the problem is image is not displayed in Gallery. But exist in file manager. How can I make that image searchable in gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 File file = null;
        try{
            String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpeg";
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileName);

            if(file.exists())
            {
                file.delete();
            }
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            template.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.close();

            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Templated saved to your device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after saving file

```
try {

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                        new String[] { mPath }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                            }
                        });

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```